# trouble with wxWidget configuration in cmake

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

I have trouble with configuring wxWidgets in cmake. It shows this error message and I dont know what to do.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we prefer error messages to be included into the **question post as text**, not linked as images. Please, [edit] your question and correct this.

Comment: Also, post the part of the `cmake` settings where it looks for wxWidgets, which version it looks for and what version you have installed.